# check if "self" inside an object has the same id as the object itself

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to python so please bear with me. I recently read that "self" inside an object has the same id as the object itself. I didn't fully understand what it means and wanted to implement what it's trying to say by printing the id using id() but I'm still not getting it can someone explain what it means by using the code I provided below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__ (self, lion, tiger):
        self.lion = lion
        self.tiger = tiger

#Does this mean the Id of the two print statments should be the same?    
print(id(lion), id(tiger))
print(id(Myclass))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyClass:
    def method(self):
        print(id(self))

obj = MyClass()
print(id(obj))
# 140425451840032
obj.method()
# 140425451840032
```

Specifically, the `self` parameter represents *the instance that the method was called on*. In python, methods are bound to the class only as a namespace, and the dot-notation we use for calling them from an instance is a syntactic shorthand. The following two lines are functionally identical:

```
obj.method()         # calling the method on an instance
MyClass.method(obj)  # calling the method on a class, passing an instance as a parameter
```

With this in mind, it should be obvious why `id(obj)` and `id(self)` return the same thing - it's the same object that they're both operating on!

Comment: Nice explanation, Thanks for the help. @Green Cloak Guy

Answer (score 1):

No. `lion` and `tiger` are different objects. And `MyClass`, you can imagine it as a object of blueprint that produces other object, thus its of course different for the previous two.

You can use the following code to check `self` equals to the object:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def compare(self, obj):
        print(id(self))
        print(id(obj))
        return id(self) == id(obj)
```

your first instantiate an object of `aa` produced by the blueprint `A` with any parameters:

```
aa = A(1)
```

then you call the method `compare` that prints and compares the id of another object and `self`. By passing the `aa`, you get the result of comparison:

```
aa.compare(aa)
```

which outputs:

```
140627467692064
140627467692064
True
```

And the result agrees with what you put in the question: **"I recently read that "self" inside an object has the same id as the object itself. "**